# Restricting Map values when using Jackson to parse JSON

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm using [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) to parse JSON where one of the fields is a dictionary of arbitrary keys and values. This would typically map directly to a Java `Map<String, Object>` were it not for the fact that we only permit certain value types (`String`, `Long`, `Double`, `Long[]` and `Double[]`).

Currently we parse the document in full, then iterate through each value of each map and perform an `instanceof` to check if it's valid or not, returning an error to the user when invalid. This is of course rather inefficient for long documents, of which we have many.

Is anyone aware of a way to express this map value type restriction to Jackson such that any errors in the input can be caught during parsing? The `@JsonSubTypes` annotation looked like it might be relevant but couldn't work out how it would be applied in this case.

Here's an example of the type of code I wish to replace:

```
static class Doc {
    List<Item> items;
}

static class Item {
    /* ...other fields snipped... */
    public Map<String, Object> payload;

    @JsonIgnore
    public void check() throws Exception {
        for(Object value: item.payload.values()) {
            if(value instanceof String) { 
            else if(value instanceof Long) { }
            else if(value instanceof Long[]) { }
            else if(value instanceof Double) { }
            else if(value instanceof Double[]) { }
            else { throw new Exception("Unsupported value type"); }
        }
    }
}

void read(InputStream stream) throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Doc doc = mapper.readValue(stream, Doc.class);

    // Check all payload types are valid
    for(Item item: doc.items) {
        item.check()
    }
}
```

Comment: Please write your source class which parse the `JSON`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, couldn't find a way to express what I wanted using Jackson's provided annotations or types system, so I ended up doing what I was trying to avoid by writing a custom deserializer instead.

Admittedly however this does allow for more concise control over permitted data types and parsing errors, but it's more verbose than I would have liked!

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a specific feature to do this, but how about creating your `Map` sub-class that throws Exception for unacceptable sub-types? Something like:

```
public class LimitedMap extends HashMap<String,Object> {
  public Object put(String key, Object value) {
     // verify it's not a Boolean or Map. And note that Jackson uses List
     // for JSON Arrays; Double for floating point (by default), Integer or Long for ints
  }
}
```

An alternative would be use of `JSON Schema` validator (many of which build on Jackson).